# Is there a Performance Penalty for LOD objects with different topology?

Tags: 3d, performance, optimization

I have a fairly complex-shaped object I've modeled, and in creating the LOD meshes, I've merged some verts, deleted some and even added some after in cases where this manipulation produced an n-gon. The UVs look fine, but these meshes have slightly different topology and vertex placement in some spots. Is this okay? What are the ramifications?

Comment: I don't understand this question. LODs *have to have* different topology. "Topology" refers to the connections between vertices. If two meshes have different numbers of vertices and triangles, the topology cannot be the same. Unless you have a different definition of "topology". Can you explain what exactly it is you are concerned about?

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the term correctly. I always assumed it meant the way that the components (vertices and edges) were laid out. I didn't only take away edge loops, in some cases I had to add/subtract edges and merge them etc.  In a case where there were two edge loops between two UV seams, I even took the original two away and added a single edge loop so that it would be squarely in the center rather than biased towards a particular direction. That means that some of the edges/loops in the lower-poly aren't present in the higher poly. Would this create a performance penalty/problem?

Comment: Topplogy in mathematics and computer graphics mean different things.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question and clarify a bit more what exactly you did. Especially when we are talking about performance details matter a lot. For example, how is your buffer layed out?

Comment: Even using the mathematical definition, exploiting topological differences in LOD are routine. Consider the case of displaying a map; it's routine for lakes and islands disappear when you zoom out. I'm unclear what "performance" means here. Is this a question about real-time APIs, or data structures for ray tracing, or what?